# How can i find `SENDER ID` in firebase?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic2

I am creating `Push notification` demo in ionic 2. I have tried to generate `server key` and `sender key` from firebase. i have follow this [tutorial](https://docs.ionic.io/services/profiles/#android-fcm-project--server-key). but I can not found `cloud messaging` tab in my firebase `project setting` screen as shown bellow image and there is no `Server key` and `sender Id`.

[image]

I need `SENDER ID` for create push notification in my app as bellow,

`cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=12341234 --save`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here is the steps,

1. Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Select your project
3. Click on `Setting` icon near to `Overview` in left panel.
4. Select `Project settings`.
5. If you have already registered your app to project then click on `CLOUD MESSAGING` tab
6. If you do not have registered you app then first register it from `Overview` tab and follow step 5.

and you'll get `Sender ID`

Answer (score 18):

Login firebase account go to project Setting. Here you can get **`Sender Id`**

[image]