# Send notification using firebase in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an ASP.NET Core application that will send some notifications using Firebase.

I am using this code to send notification messages by C#.

Startup.cs

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //...
   FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
   {
       Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "key.json")),
   });
   //...
}
```

and here is the code how I send the notification

```
try
{
    string ServerKey = "MY_SERVER_KEY";

    var message = new Message()
    {
        Notification = new Notification
        {
            Title = "Message Title",
            Body = "Message Body"
        },
        Token = ServerKey,             
    };

    return await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

The problem is after I run my function to send a notification I get the following error:

> SenderId mismatch

I checked the documentation and some other place I didn't find how can I put the Sender Id.

Comment: seems like key is wrong(maybe old) get the right key from console

Comment: Or key is bindined to external IP/dns name ... of course it's not written in the question itself so the question is unclear ... I can say with right `Token` and key file this code works for me fine ... I don't understand why this has +2 (more likely voting irregularities)

Comment: here is the way how I got the key server
Project settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Project credentials - >Server key

Comment: Lol ... read what Token is ... **it's not Server Key** (*These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.*) ... more over if you get this error it means that your server key was from different app then you key.json file (in other case nothing would be happend - no error, nothing send)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292516/how-can-i-find-sender-id-in-firebase on how to find the correct sender ID for your project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, I have the Sender Id but where can I put it?

Comment: *I have the Sender Id  but where can I put it?* ... leave it ... you need registration token(not some unrelated ServerKey) to be  sended as `Message.Token` to send message to user which is connected with registration  token

Comment: I got it now, I misunderstand everything, my real problem is to send notifications to all users, and I was thinking that token is something similar to the Target user segment.

Comment: you may register all users(in client app of course) to some global topic and then send messages to this topic

Comment: that is my problem, I don't know if should I update my question? @Selvin